# How can I find date range in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to search data within the given date range. I have a database with having details of name, venue, start_at and end_at. I can search name and venue by defining find method in controller.following is my controller code.

```
def find
  @events=Event.find(:all, :conditions=>["venue = ? OR name = ?", params[:search_string], params[:search_string]])
end
```

Then it will find venue or name. But when I add start_at into this code it will return an exception. how can i search relevant date range from the database? plz anybody can help me? I am using postgresql and ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.8 versions.

I changed my find method as follows...

```
def find    
  if (params[:search_string])
    @events=Event.find(:all, :conditions=>["venue = ? OR name = ?", params[:search_string], params[:search_string]])
  else 
    @events= Event.all(:conditions => ["start_at >= ? AND end_at <= ?",  params[:start_at], params[:end_at]])
  end
end
```

first if statement was properly working. but else part is not working. there is no exception. it will not retrieve date related data from database. I add this if statement into my code due to not retrieving data. can anybody help me to correct this second part? I enter date in my search textbox. but it will not retrieve any data.

Comment: what exception? and how did you `add start_at into this code`?

Comment: start_at is date variable i add this as  def find

  @events=Event.find(:all, :conditions=>["venue = ? OR name = ? OR start_at = ?", params[:search_string], params[:search_string],, params[:search_string]])
end

Comment: start_at in your example is a STRING not a DATE.

Comment: yeah start_at is a date....how can i change this?

Comment: Why do you mark an answer as accepted if the question is not answered yet? If people think your question is answered they will not look at it anymore.

Comment: I am really sorry.. Iam novel to the stack flow and i just wanted to say it will not throw any exceptions. I add comment under his comment. Anyway iam still finding a way to do this. Plz help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a way to search a data within given date range. I did this separately.I created two text_field_tag in my layout and created controller code as follow.

```
    def find
    @events= Event.all(:conditions => ["start_at >= ? AND end_at <= ?",  params[:search], params[:search_string]])

    end
```

Then I added following code in layout.

```
    <span style="text-align: right">
    <% form_tag "/events/find" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search%>
    <%= text_field_tag :search_string %>
    <%= submit_tag "search" %>
    <% end %>
    </span>
```

I got data from database.. Now I want to combine these two. finding a data by date range needs two text_field_tag and finding a data by name only need one text_field _tag. So how can I do this? need your help further more....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
Try something like:

```
@events = Event.where("(venue = ? OR name = ?) AND start_at >= ? AND end_at <= ?", params[:search_string], params[:search_string], params[:start_at], params[:end_at])
```

**Edit**

In Rails 2.3.x, it should be

```
@events = Event.all(:conditions => ["(venue = ? OR name = ?) AND start_at >= ? AND end_at <= ?", params[:search_string], params[:search_string], params[:start_at], params[:end_at]])
```

Notice that the conditions is given as an array.

Comment: it is not working...again i got exception. undefined method `where' for #<Class:0x45a1b38>

Comment: How about posting that exception? :)

Comment: Yeah, @Octopus-Paul gave you Rails 3.x example

Comment: what class is Event? (It should be something like class Event < ActiveRecord::Base ...

Comment: I changed this "where" to find then also got an exception..           "Couldn't find all Events with IDs (0,0) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)"

Comment: yeah Event is inherit from ActiveRecord class.                        i am using rails 2.3.8

Comment: @rosh...I have edited his answer for Rails 2.3.8, please try.

Comment: there are no exceptions now. but it will not retrieve any data from database..... Thanks rubyprince